# Upgrade to 14.04, Banshee behaves differently with podcasts on iPod

Tags: banshee, ipod

I upgraded to 14.04 recently, and when I used Banshee to add a podcast I had downloaded to my iPod, it added it to the "podcasts" section. Before I had upgraded, the podcasts I had added to my iPod were just added to my "music" section. I tried to move the new podcast to the music section, but there was no option for it that I could find. I don't mind where it is, I just want consistency. Is there a way to move the podcast back into the music section? Or to move the old podcasts in my music section into the podcast section? I appreciate the help!